# Python class variable is set in init, but then not defined in save

Tags: python, django, exception

I have a Django form, in which I set the value of a variable in the `__init__` method, and then try to save it in the `save` method. However, when I load the webpage in my browser, the console indicates that the variable is not defined when I try to use it in the `save` method:

```
class abcForm(ValidatedForm):
    ...
    projectInstance = None
    ...
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
        project = instance.project
        ...
        projectInstance = project
        ...

    def save(self, commit=True):
        ...
            if 'date_received' in self.changed_data:
                if not data['date_received'] == '':
                    ...
                    projectInstance.date_deposit_received = deposit.date_received
                    ...
                else:
                    ...
                ...
            ...
            return ...
```

The exception that I'm getting in the console says:

```
NameError: global name 'projectInstance' is not defined
[25/Nov/2016 13:28:54] "POST /projects/6311/concept_save_ajax/ HTTP/1.1" 500 19430
Exception in thread Thread-42:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Users/elgan/Documents/Dev/moonhub/moon/core/models.py", line 138, in run
    msg.send(self.fail_silently)
  File "/Users/elgan/.virtualenvs/moon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 292, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/Users/elgan/.virtualenvs/moon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 100, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/Users/elgan/.virtualenvs/moon/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 615, in login
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, '5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful')
```

What I don't understand is why the exception is telling me that `projectInstance` is not defined, when it has clearly been defined in the `__init__` method...?

This exception only occurs when I try to change the value of the `date_received` field in the form- not when I change the value of any of the text boxes... Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit**

Ok, so I've added a few print statements, and I think I know why the `date` field on my form is displaying the old value, and not the updated one after a page refresh- I think it's because the new value is not being saved to the instance of the object in the Python code- only the JS variable displaying the date is being changed... The JS that's being run when a change is detected on the `datepicker` field is:

```
if (window.confirm("Would you like to send an email confirming we have received a deposit?")) {
    console.log("'if(window.confirm)' statement entered in concept.html JS... ")

    var date = $(this).val()
    if (date){
        date = date.split('/')
        var new_date = [];
        new_date = new_date.concat(date[2]).concat(date[1]).concat(date[0]);
        new_date = new_date.join('-');
    }
    if (new_date != $(this).data('original-value')){
    // CDI fee date has been changed from nothing to something
        console.log("It's changed")
        /* Set the original-value so it won't send multiple times */
        $(this).data('original-value', new_date) /*ERF(24/11/2016 @ 1700) This line should be copying the value of new_date to the 'original-value', so original value should now hold the new date... */
        //$(this).data('original-value') = new_date

        // Send email to relevant people
        var url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=5"
        console.log('Url', url)
        $.post(url)
            .done(function(response){
                console.log('Email sent')
            })
    }
}
/*} */
else{
    console.log("'else' of 'if(window.confirm)' statement entered in concept.html JS... ")
    var date = $(this).val()
    if (date){
        date = date.split('/')
        var new_date = [];
        new_date = new_date.concat(date[2]).concat(date[1]).concat(date[0]);
        new_date = new_date.join('-');
        console.log("Value of date in if(date): ", date)
    }
    if (new_date != $(this).data('original-value')){
        // CDI fee date has been changed from nothing to something
        /*ERF(28/11/2016 @ 0935) Fee date was not necessarily nothing- need to change its value when it had a date
                    previously stored in it too...
                    Print the values of 'new_date' and 'original-value' here. */
        console.log("Value of new_date: ", new_date)
        console.log("Value of original-value: ", this.data)
        console.log("It's changed")
        // Set the original-value so it won't send multiple times
        $(this).data('original-value', new_date) /*ERF(28/11/2016 @ 0950) This line isn't actually setting the original value to the value of 'new_date'... */
        id_date_received = new_date
        console.log("Value of id_date_received: ", id_date_received)
        // Send email to relevant people
        var url="{% url 'comms:open_email_template' project.id %}?template=5"
        console.log('Url', url)
        $.post(url)
            .done(function(response){
                console.log('Email sent')
            })
    }
}
```

The `console.log()` statements that I've added show that the value of the `date_received` variable is updated when the user selects a new date, but when I refresh the page, it's the old value that has automatically populated the date field- not the new one, even though my code appears to be updating its value.

The Python `__init__` function for this form is:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print "__init__ method being called in DepositInfoForm"
    instance = kwargs.get('instance', {})
    project = instance.project

    try: amount_exc_vat = int(round(instance.amount_exc_vat))
    except TypeError: amount_exc_vat = None
    print "amount_exc_vat has been set: ", amount_exc_vat
    try: amount_inc_vat = int(round(project.deposit.amount_inc_vat))
    except TypeError: amount_inc_vat = None
    print "amount_inc_vat has been set: ", amount_inc_vat
    try: date_received = instance.date_received
    except TypeError: date_received = None
    print "date_received has been set: ", date_received

    initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
    initial={
                'received': project.deposit_received,
                'amount_exc_vat': amount_exc_vat,
                'amount_inc_vat': amount_inc_vat,

                'date_received': date_received,

                }
    kwargs['initial'] = initial

    self.projectInstance = project
    print "projectInstance has been set to project in __init__"

    super(DepositInfoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['date_received'].widget.attrs.update({'data-original-value': self.initial['date_received'] or ''})
```

It seems that for some reason, the last line in the `__init__` function is not actually updating the widget to the value of `date_received`... anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: `self.projectInstance`

Comment: what @algrebe said + you are assuming that instance.project is defined in `__init__`

Comment: Thanks, I gave that a try, but now when loading the page in the browser, and selecting a different 'date' value, the console shows an error that says: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'date_deposit_received'... I guess this is talking about the `deposit` variable that I've defined with: `deposit = self.instance`?

Comment: @someone2088 In `__init__` you are setting `projectInstance` , not `self.projectInstance`. Have you changed that ? If not, then `self.projectInstance` in the save method will still be None.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. That's partially resolved it... if I now change the date, then one of the `int` values, and then refresh the page, the new values for both the `int` and the 'date' are displayed on the form. However, if I just change the 'date' field, and refresh the page, the old date is what's displayed in the form... Why won't this save the new value when only the 'date' field value is changed?

Comment: @someone2088:  please post the rest of your code, and we can help you.

Comment: I've posted more of my code- having done a bit more investigation, I think I've narrowed down why/ where the code isn't updating the date field displayed, but I'm not sure how I fix this...